# Error "The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file", when root element does match the name of the section

Tags: c#, config

I am trying to move appSettings config section to an external file using "file" attribute and keep getting the error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : The root element
>   must match the name of the section referencing the file, 'appSettings'

The problem is that root element in the external file is already 'appSettings'.
Tried using root 'configuration' and custom config Sections, and it didn't help either

External file `Test.config` is below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="URL" value="https://www.google.com" />
</appSettings>
```

Main `App.config` file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  </specFlow>
  <appSettings file="Test.config"/>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this was a path issue.  The default behavior from visual studio is to not include the file in the output directory.  I changed the file properties to "Copy Always" for each build to ensure you have the most recent file.  If you have added it to your project in the properties section then the file reference should include the properties folder in the path.